# htaccess 404 redirect works for every extension or path except for .php

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, http-status-code-404, file-extension

I have added the following line to my .htaccess file

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

It seems to be working fine, except for any non-existent address ending with the .php extension. In that case, a message with the text "File not found." appears instead.

Any clues about what could be causing this to happen only on .php pages?

Comment: Apache won't check your code for 404 routes, you would need to do that in code.

Answer (score 0):

With ModRewrite On:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
ErrorDocument 404 404.php/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/404/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ 404.php [L]
```

Comment: Still not working for .php files. Anything else works fine.

Comment: @Paulo could you post your server logs? Or give us a link to.php that doesn't exist.